# How to create an IF statement in Python when working with files?

Tags: python

I am struggling to work with files.

I have two files like this:

```
Document 1 987.docx
Document 1 Abc.docx
```

I have a variable:
`x = "Document 1.docx"`

How can I create an `if` statement to say..
If `Document 1.docx` with any random word after the `1` appears twice in the folder, then `Print("True")`

This is where I got to:

```
import os
import glob

directory = "C:/Users/hawk/Desktop/Test" # directory
choices = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, "*")) # returns all files in the folder
print(choices) #shows all files from the directory 

x = "Document 1.docx"
```

Comment: Please avoid external links and include this information as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the `glob` syntax to filter down your files, then just check if anything was found:

```
import glob
import os

filename_prefix = 'Document 1'

# For simplicity, I'm just using current directory.
# This can be whatever you need, like in your question
directory = '.'

# Looks for any files whose name starts with filename_prefix ("Document 1")
# and has a "docx" extension.
choices = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '{prefix}*.docx'.format(prefix=filename_prefix)))

# Evaluates to True if any files were found from glob, False
# otherwise (choices will be an empty list)
if any(choices):
    print('Files with', filename_prefix, 'found!')
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a job for regex:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'^Document 1 ')   #m
count = 0
for line in choices:
    if pattern.search(line):
        count += 1
if count >= 2:                   #use == if you only want doubles not triples
    print("True")
```

This will capture any filename beginning with "Document 1" followed by a space, but not for example "Document 1name.docx". For that something like:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'^Document 1( |[a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])+\.docx$')
```

Should work (as long as there's no punctuation).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I Have an error showing up  `if regex.search(line):
TypeError: search() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'`

Comment: As written, ```choices``` should be a list of strings... perhaps you are using ```re.search(line)```? In that case you would be calling the search function from the module... see edit, i.e. this is also acceptable format: ```if re.search(pattern, line):```

Comment: Thanks, it works without any errors, but does not return anything unfortunately, sorry

Comment: Might be that glob is adding on the path names to each string? Try removing the ```^``` in the regex pattern. Also take a look at pydocs for the re module.